# " undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass "

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
<% 
 @loans.each do |loan_rec| 
  loan=loan_rec.info 
  if loan['_LoanName'].blank?
    loan_name = 'No Loan Title'
  else
    loan_name = loan['_LoanName']
  end
end
%>
```

I am getting error of `` undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass ``. What is undefined? and when I print `loan` array in a loop, it gives the following result:

```
{
  "_LendingCategory"=>"Private Real Estate Loan",
  "Email"=>"entregeorge@gmail.com",
  "FirstName"=>"TestDavid",
  "Id"=>3573,
  "_LoanName"=>"null",
  "LastName"=>"TestGeorge",
  "_DesiredTermLength"=>"3",
  "_TransactionType0"=>"Purchase",
  "_CashContribution"=>100000.0,
  "_NetLoanAmountRequested0"=>8000000.0
}
```

Comment: what is the value of load_rec.info?

Comment: When we print "loan_rec.info" It's giving : {"_LendingCategory"=>"Private Real Estate Loan", "Email"=>"entregeorge@gmail.com", "FirstName"=>"TestDavid", "Id"=>3573, "_LoanName"=>"null", "LastName"=>"TestGeorge", "_DesiredTermLength"=>"3", "_TransactionType0"=>"Purchase", "_CashContribution"=>100000.0, "_NetLoanAmountRequested0"=>8000000.0}

Comment: on what line it is giving error?

Comment: What is `info` on your `Loan` model? Is it a `has_one` to another model?

Answer (score 3):

You have at least one `Loan` for which `loan_rec.info` is `nil`. You can try:

```
loan = loan_rec.info || Loan.new
```

as a quick fix, but you should also figure figure out how to avoid the `nil` in the first place.

Comment: better: loan = loan_rec.try(:info) || Loan.new

Answer (score 1):

In your `loan`, there is no any `info` key. So you would have at aleast one `info` value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to anticipate that there might not be an `info` for every `loan_rec`.  I would refactor your code like this:

```
<% 
  @loans.each do |loan_rec| 
    loan = loan_rec.info 
    loan_name = loan && loan['_LoanName']
    if loan_name.blank?
      loan_name = 'No Loan Title'
    end
  end
%>
```